# Hierachically flatten MongoDB collection of documents with arrays into documents

Tags: arrays, mongodb, dictionary, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Block model (which goes on block 0 -> block 1 -> block 2 -> block 3 -> […]):

[image: https://yuml.me/cb86229d.png]

Example input document [700+ of these in the `modulestore.structures` collection]:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('5932d50ff8f46c0a8098ab79'),
  blocks: [
    {
      definition: ObjectId('5923556ef8f46c0a787e9c0f'),
      block_type: 'chapter',
      block_id: '5b053a7f10ba41df85a3221c3ef3956e',
      fields: {
        format: 'Foo exam',
        children: [ 
          [ 
            'sequential', 
            '9f1e58553ad448818ec8e7915d3d94d3'
          ], 
          [ 
            'sequential', 
            'f052c7aa44274769a4631e95405834e0'
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      definition: ObjectId('59235569f8f46c0a7be1debc'),
      block_type: 'sequential',
      block_id: '9f1e58553ad448818ec8e7915d3d94d3',
      fields: {
        display_name: 'FooBar'
      }
    },
    {
      definition: ObjectId('59317406f8f46c0a8098aaf5'),
      block_type: 'sequential',
      block_id: 'f052c7aa44274769a4631e95405834e0',
      fields: {
        display_name: 'CanHaz'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My goal here is to:

1. flatten out the blocks so all blocks are at the collection level;
2. cursor the `children` array for traversal;
3. walk and amend the 'tree' such that each child/grandchild/great-grandchild/*-child gets a new property `top_ancestor_fields` containing the `fields` property from their topmost ancestor.

Example output:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId('5a00f611f995363c2b63c9a6'),
    block_type: 'chapter',
    block_id: '5b053a7f10ba41df85a3221c3ef3956e',
    fields: {
      format: 'Foo exam'
      children: [ 
        [ 
          'sequential',
          '9f1e58553ad448818ec8e7915d3d94d3'
        ], 
        [
          'sequential',
          'f052c7aa44274769a4631e95405834e0'
        ]
      ]
    },
    top_ancestor_fields: {
      format: 'Foo exam'
    }
  },
  {
     _id: ObjectId('5a00f611f995363c2b63c9a7'),
     block_id: '9f1e58553ad448818ec8e7915d3d94d3',
     block_type: 'sequential',
     fields: {
       display_name: 'FooBar'
     },
     top_ancestor_fields: {
       format: 'Foo exam'
     }
  },
  {
     _id: ObjectId('5a00f611f995363c2b63c9a8'),
     block_id: 'f052c7aa44274769a4631e95405834e0',
     block_type: 'sequential',
     fields: {
       display_name: 'CanHaz'
     },
     top_ancestor_fields: {
       format: 'Foo exam'
     }
  },
]
```

---

Almost have it working based off @neil-lunn's suggestion:

```
db.modulestore.structures.aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$blocks' },
  { $project: { _id: 0,
                block_id: '$blocks.block_id',
                children: '$blocks.fields.children',
                display_name: '$blocks.fields.display_name',
                block_type: '$blocks.block_type',
                exam: '$blocks.fields.format',
                fields: '$blocks.fields'
               }},
  { $out: 'modulestore.mapped0' }
])

db.modulestore.mapped0.aggregate([
    { $graphLookup: {
        from: 'modulestore.mapped0',
        startWith: '$block_id',
        connectToField: 'children',
        connectFromField: 'block_id',
        as: 'block_ids',
        maxDepth: 0
    } },
    { $unwind: '$block_ids' },
    { $project: {
        name: 1,
        _id: 0,
        ancestor: '$block_ids.block_id'
    } },
    { $out: 'modulestore.mapped1' }
]);
```

But this just hangs. I've tried configuring `maxDepth` [`$graphLookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) option. FYI: `db.modulestore.mapped0.count()` is 80772 for me.

Each document potentially contains a `children` array with up to 180 elements.

Not sure how to approach this larger pipeline to map `children` hierarchies…

Comment: [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). You certainly don't want `mapReduce` and you would know why as soon as you output anything since it's not really going to respect your document format and forces `{ "_id": <key>, "value": <value> }` with no possible way to change that. It's really not clear what you want here other than "unwinding" an array.

Comment: Don't get it. What are you expecting as output? If you have 10 documents and each "document" has 5 array entries, then `$unwind` **will** give you 10 x 5 = 50 documents output. Being one for each array member. Also kind of elaborating on the original comment, saying "PPS" does not really tell us anything about what you intend to do here. Perhaps you really mean `$unwind` the "children" as well? But you don't really clearly state what should happen or even why you need this. New collection? Further aggregation? All kind of a mystery. Should have commented back rather than putting up a bounty.

Comment: unclear how you would unwind the child array of referenced documents?

Comment: So I want each child to have a property from its uppermost ancestor. E.g.: the fields property [becoming `top_ancestor_fields`].

Comment: @AT Again, you still are not really explaining "what you expect". The most simple way is to "show the source" ( which you have done ), but also show "the **expected** output" from that source derived "within your question". If you have problems with a particular approach, then show what exactly is wrong. Using `$graphLookup` should not be necessary for a single nested level. If you actually have multiple nesting, then actually show that "in the question" so there is a sample people can use and see your expected results from.

Comment: @AT  You may also need to accept that your chosen storage format may not suit the "output" or indeed the "queries" you may need to perform on the data as a whole. So you should "explain your purpose". These are the things you "must" present when asking a question of your peers, otherwise answers will not address all the things you can think of but did not actually present the same case of data you actually have for others to see. Also use the `@` thingy like I have to "notify" others of your changes in comments. Otherwise we just don't see them.

Comment: Okay I've added a diagram and a better explanation. @NeilLunn - I am trying to traverse each block's children array and give each child block an attribute from its topmost ancestor block (not necessarily its immediate parent block).

Comment: @AT You know the saying "A picture is worth a thousand words"? This would be one case where I would say I would prefer the 1000 words instead. It doesn't really clarify at all. Just give us a sample document of what you expect the output to look like as obtained from the data you actually give us. And make sure the data you are actually giving us does represent whatever "nesting" you typically do have. You put a bounty on the question because you didn't get an answer. But you didn't get an answer because you still are not explaining what you want. Trying to help here.

Comment: @NeilLunn Okay, I think it's a little clearer now. Being able to traverse the children array and inherit everything from its topmost ancestor is the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: More lost than ever. I cannot see anything in here other than this `ancestor` field which appears to be simply the `block_id` from the "first" array element being repeated in the subsequent elements. Otherwise it's pretty much a straight up `$unwind`. I can't see how `$graphLookup` has anything to do with this. Seemingly all you want is to copy that value to the other array elements other than the "first". Unless of course you still really are not explaining what is supposed to happen here.

Comment: Okay since that must've been confusing; I've removed the ancestor field from the output objects.

Comment: Have you tried even explaining this to someone else at work, and then get some feedback on whether they have a clue what you are even asking? That might be something you want to do to give you a perspective on how you need to explain it to us.

Comment: To be clear. I want every `{block_id, block_type, children, fields}` document to contain the `fields` object of their uppermost ancestor. So to trace the children array members down: `block0->block1->block2->block3`. `block3` should get the `fields` object of `block0`.

Comment: Seriously, take a look at how many comments are here. I might be that somehow "I just don't get it" and someone else does. But a lack of answers really should indicate that the intent here is not that clear at all. You just even discounted the only thing I can see as a difference to simply unwinding the array, so it's not really encouraging. Get some external feedback on your "elevator pitch" and then come back when you have something more concise. And `@` thingy. USE IT!! I'm not going to sit here looking all day.

Comment: @NeilLunn 0) There is a hierarchy implied by the `children` array, yes? - 1) `children` array gives two IDs which can be used to find each child. - 2) Each child might have their own `children` array and so forth. - 3) So I want to traverse to all the children such that each child gets the contents of the top of their hierarchy; specifically the `fields` object (`block.fields`).

Comment: @NeilLunn I've hacked together pseudo code that is easy to translate to Python [which I'll do later today]. It's algorithmically terrible, I would much prefer to have this in a Mongo query or two all done server-side. Earlier today I tried writing it in: Rust; C++; and Go. But none of their client libraries had adequate flexibility to handle flexible schemes; with the exception of C++ which had a linking error with pkg-config (worked with CMake)

Comment: @NeilLunn - Python attempt now added.

Answer (score 1):

The following should get you started:

```
db.modulestore.structures.aggregate([{
    $unwind: '$blocks' // flatten "blocks" array
}, {
    $replaceRoot: { // move "blocks" field to top level
        newRoot: "$blocks"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: { // flatten "fields.children" array
        path: "$fields.children",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
}, {
    // this step is technically not needed but it might speed up things - try running with and without that
    $addFields: { // we only keep the second (last, really) entry of all your arrays since this is the only valid join key for the graphLookup
        "fields.children": {
            $slice: [ "$fields.children", -1 ]
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: { // flatten "fields.children" array one more time because it was nested before
        path: "$fields.children",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
}, {
    $group: { // reduce the number of lookups required later by eliminating duplicate parent-child paths
        "_id": "$block_id",
        "block_type": { $first: "$block_type" },
        "definition": { $first: "$definition" },
        "fieldsFormat": { $first: "$fields.format" },
        "fieldsChildren": { $addToSet: "$fields.children" }
    }
}, {
    $project: { // restore original structure
        "block_id": "$_id",
        "block_type": "$block_type",
        "definition": "$definition",
        "fields": {
            "format": "$fieldsFormat",
            "children": "$fieldsChildren"
        }
    }
}, { // spit out the result into "modulestore.mapped0" collection, overwriting all existing content
    $out: 'modulestore.mapped0'
}])
```

and then

```
db.modulestore.mapped0.aggregate([{
    $graphLookup: {
        from: 'modulestore.mapped0',
        startWith: '$block_id',
        connectToField: 'fields.children',
        connectFromField: 'block_id',
        as: 'block_ids',
        maxDepth: 0
    }
}, { 
    $lookup: { 
        from: 'modulestore.mapped0', 
        localField: 'block_ids.fields.children', 
        foreignField: '_id', 
        as: 'block_ids.fields.children' 
    } 
}])
```

Comment: Thanks, I got some output from this, then I dropped all collections in my db except `modulestore.structures` and added `{ $out: 'modulestore.mapped1'}` below `$graphLookup`. Now it just hangs…

Comment: Thanks @dnickless - Take a look at my Python solution and see if you can't implement that 'properly' (i.e.: in DB). - Bounty almost expired

Comment: Have you tried my updated approach already? I came up with a more efficient one than the first suggestion after which you commented initially.

Comment: Hmm I'll see what I can make from it later @dnickless - it clearly doesn't get me the topmost ancestor, but possibly it simplifies the successive queries on the dataset. But I need to figure out what successive queries are required to populate a `topmost_ancestor_fields` on each block.

Comment: No, it should still give you the right return values.

Comment: I'll give you the bounty because it's about to expire. It doesn't give what I wanted though. Maybe it's almost there? - How do I map the IDs within the children array? - Trying to get the block each refers to… - Will then filter out a few fields (or just JSON.stringify) for each referred block.

Comment: My horrible Python attempt: https://gist.github.com/AlecTaylor/c4aed497959e5ca15c5f40dff25bdb99

Comment: Let me say a humble "thank you" for the bounty - I don't think I deserve it yet but I'll try hard to get that fixed. So... The latest MongoDB based "solution" that I suggested above - does it still result in a time out? Do you definitely want to go down the iterative python way? If so, what exactly is the problem? Can you perhaps add some comment about that in your gist?

Comment: Happy to award that; you got further than I did! - So to clarify: your solution now produces output without error in less than 1s on MongoDB. - I've upgraded to MongoDB 3.6 BTW. - Okay, so my goal is to get not just the IDs of all the children blocks but also their contents. - So what you gave me - b0: `10101, children: [b1]` b1: `1111, children: [b2]` I want: to be `10101, children: [1111]`. I.e.: that the full content of each referenced block gets placed in the children array.

Comment: "In less than 1s" - that sounds really nice!

Would you kindly e.g. update your question or or your gist or something so I understand the desired structure properly?

Comment: Updated the gist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158976/discussion-between-a-t-and-dnickless).

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution [[gist](https://gist.github.com/AlecTaylor/47d058a79beea24d655336527c831376)]:

```
def update_descendants(modulestore, blocks, ancestor_fields):
    """    
    :keyword modulestore: modulestore containing the blocks
    :type modulestore: ``Collection``   

    :keyword blocks: iterator over the blocks (collections within modulestore)
    :type blocks: ``Cursor`` | `tuple`

    :keyword ancestor_fields: fields of the top most ancestor
    :type ancestor_fields: ``dict``
    """
for block in blocks:
    modulestore.replace_one({'block_id': block['block_id'],
                             'block_type': block['block_type']},
                            update_d(block, add={'ancestor_fields': ancestor_fields},
                                     rm=('_id',)))
    update_descendants.counter += 1
    print 'Updated:', update_descendants.counter

    if 'children' in block and block['children']:
        for block_type, block_id in block['children']:
            update_descendants(modulestore,
                               modulestore.find({'block_id': block_id,
                                                 'block_type': block_type,
                                                 'ancestor_fields': {
                                                     '$exists': False
                                                 }}),
                               ancestor_fields)
```

Would prefer a solution that's wholly in the database though, and without all these inefficient queries.